# TSNE interpreration and separability

Tags: machine-learning-model, tsne, binary-classification

I have a binary classification problem where I train a neural network on a training and validation data sets. But I am not satisfied with the performance of my trained classifier (the NN above). The `loss function` (a binary cross entropy) did not get lower than 0.1280 the on validation set and on the test set it is about 0.1340. I tried to somehow debug my data with a `TSNE` to visualize how "separable" my training data is.

My question is,

- can a TSNE visualisation give a feel of how much my data is separable and allow me to predict the performance of a classifier?
  It is clear from the image above that my data is not linearly separable but what else does it say about my data.
- Do you have any idea about how to improve separability?

[image]

Comment: From your graph you should have a relatively good performance. However, how you define what notion of performance you want to use is up to you and not perfectly clear for us. Why aren't you satisfied why the eprformance of your NN ?

Comment: I agree.  It seems like you have good separation with a somewhat difficult to predict margin between them, so your performance may be on point.  TSNE might not directly translate from what I understand of it, but it should give a general impression.  You can also try UMAP, which will give more reproducible results, but will likely end up looking similar to this.  So, you can either play with the capacity and learning of your network, or try and extract a different feature space I would say (or even clean up your data in some way).